# Align center Graphs using amCharts

Tags: charts, amcharts

[image]

I have this graph, built by engine amCharts, i have 3 type fields and 3 graphs

- yellow
- green
- blue

  ```
   var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
   graph1.type = "column";
   graph1.valueField = "yellow";
   chart.addGraph(graph1);

   var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
   graph2.type = "column";
   graph2.valueField = "yellow";
   chart.addGraph(graph2);

   var graph3 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
   graph3.type = "column";
   graph3.valueField = "yellow";
   chart.addGraph(graph3);
  ```

As you can see, i  have no data for Yellow in March, May, and no data for Green in May.

I want that columns in every month aligns center like next

[image]

Comment: Great question. I would recommend also asking on the [Amcharts forum](http://www.amcharts.com/forum/).  The developer is usually very responsive to questions.

Comment: I have tried, but no answer:)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible. And we do answer to all questions...

Answer (score 0):

you can change x value in css file 
like this .amcharts-graph-column-element { x: 0.3 }